# Global BreakpointObserver?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating a web-app using Angular and Angular Material. I am in the process of making the app responsive, and hence using `BreakpointObserver` provided by Angular Material.

I am confused as to what is the right way to use `BreakpointObserver`.

Should I:-

1. Inject `BreakpointObserver` in **app.component.ts**(root component) and subscribe to changes, and whenever there is a change the components will be notified using ngrx.
2. Inject `BreakpointObserver` in every component's constructor, and subscribe to it and unsubscribe on destroy.
3. Create a service and inject `BreakpointObserver` in it and subscribe to changes. All components will then inject this service and will be notified of changes.

Is there any other way to achieve this, and which would be the better option?

Comment: If you care only about responsive design, I highly recommend using [NG flex layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) and its [responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API), which includes material breakpoints by default.

Comment: It would be good idea to hide a service from 3rd party from your components. If you want to change it in the future, you can do it in one place instead of everywhere. Also, having a centralized service for this will let you build some common logic when the resolution changes.

Comment: use 2nd option, but only for components that need it. I have been using it directly in the constructor, and the unsubscribe it ngOnDestroy